# How to turn a string into and array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, drupal

I have this string saved in my database:

```
'Array\n
(\n
   [id] => xxx111\n
   [amount] => 2000\n
   [currency] => usd\n
   [created] => xxx222\n
   [object] => refund\n
   [balance_transaction] => xxx333\n
   [charge] => xxx444\n
   [receipt_number] => xxx555\n
   [reason] => requested_by_customer\n
)'
```

and I need to parse it some how into and array(). The `\n` don't appear to be in the DB, just when I retrieve them and I check the value in Xdebug do the `\n` show up.

I've tried using `eval()` like so:

```
eval('$my_array = ' . $string_from_db . ';');
```

But it doesn't work like that because of the `[]`s for the indexes instead of `""`s. I tried some string replaces to switch them and add some commas but my regex-fu isn't that great.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't want a string at all. i want it to be converted into an array somehow. (ie  `array( "id" => 'xxx111', "amount" => 2000,` ... etc

Comment: Edited my answer below

Comment: That format is "lossy" and is only meant for debugging purposes; there are many cases where you won't be able to parse this data back into the original array unambiguously. Is this a one-time accident which you need to fix, or is this something you hope to be doing as a matter of course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$str ='Array\n
(\n
  [id] => xxx111\n
  [amount] => 2000\n
  [currency] => usd\n
  [created] => xxx222\n
  [object] => refund\n
  [balance_transaction] => xxx333\n
  [charge] => xxx444\n
  [receipt_number] => xxx555\n
  [reason] => requested_by_customer\n
)';

preg_match_all("/\[(.*)\].* => (\w+)/", $str, $arr);

$narr ="";

For($i=0;$i<=count($arr[1])-1;$i++)    {
   $narr[$arr[1][$i]] = $arr[2][$i];
}

Var_dump($narr);

?>
```

Edited to a sure method that works. Tested it with an online php site.

Comment: I seriously doubt OP would like to keep the `\n`s.  ;P

Comment: A str_replace could fix that.

Comment: turns out this works, but only for cases similar to what i posted. turns out i have some data that go into multi levelled arrays and this won't work for that.

Comment: That is probably true. What does the string look like in those cases? I'm not sure I can do it, but I can give it a try. Is your expected result to get a multidimensional array as output or several separate arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You have a helluva problem there. If can change how that value is recorded to the database, I highly recommend you use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

If you can't, then there's this:

```
$a = "Array\n
(\n
   [id] => xxx111\n
   [amount] => 2000\n
   [currency] => usd\n
   [created] => xxx222\n
   [object] => refund\n
   [balance_transaction] => xxx333\n
   [charge] => xxx444\n
   [receipt_number] => xxx555\n
   [reason] => requested_by_customer\n
)";

function parse_key($str) {
    preg_match('/\[([^]]+)\]/', $str, $m);
    return $m[1];
}

function array_from_nasty_string($s) {
    return array_reduce(array_slice(preg_split("/\n+/", $s), 2, -1), function($b, $x) {
        list($key, $value) = preg_split('/\s*=>\s*/', $x);
        $b[parse_key($key)] = $value;
        return $b;
    }, []);
}

var_dump(array_from_nasty_string($a));
```

Output

```
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "xxx111"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(4) "2000"
  ["currency"]=>
  string(3) "usd"
  ["created"]=>
  string(6) "xxx222"
  ["object"]=>
  string(6) "refund"
  ["balance_transaction"]=>
  string(6) "xxx333"
  ["charge"]=>
  string(6) "xxx444"
  ["receipt_number"]=>
  string(6) "xxx555"
  ["reason"]=>
  string(21) "requested_by_customer"
}
```

You'll notice everything is treated as a string. Even things like `[amount]=>2000\n` that was probably an integer before that. But, that's pretty much the best you're going to get.

Comment: turns out i can use json_decode. i just had to find the stop where it stored it into the DB. Originally I assumed i couldn't modify that part of the code. but luckily i can. :)

Comment: That's great. It's a much better solution than parsing the string.

Answer (score 0):

Messy and ugly , but should do the trick

```
$array();
$tmparray=explode("\n",$str);
foreach($tmparray as $row){
   if(strpos($row,'>')!==false){
     $tab2=explode(">",$row);
     $array[trim(substr(trim($tab2[0]),1,-3))]=trim($tab2[1]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: this one is so close!! the array indexes have the `]` on it still. otherwise its perfect.

Comment: try now - it'a all about substr third parametr